# Universal Rest Client in C# for different REST API's

Tags: c#, json, rest, client

I want to write a REST client in C# that could read about API calls from a config file, process the JSON response and generate csv files accordingly. 
There would be another config file that would include attributes returned with each API call. This client should read this template config file and process the response.

Client should be such that it could be used with all 3rd party rest api's that generates JSON response. Only difference would be that there would be different config file and template file for each data source.

Is there any other way to achieve above functionality ?
Is there any 3rd party library available that could help to achieve this ?
What should be a good design approach to achieve this ?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: It sounds like you might be looking for a tool like Swagger.io?

Comment: What if I give API methods in a XML file, write a XML parser to fetch and execute those methods on API Server. Store the response in a data structure. Parse template JSON file and do look up on API response output to process the final output and then generate csv's. Does it sound like a scalable approach  ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. There is a way to achieve this functionality, but it sounds as though you are asking multiple questions here. You should probably break your question up in to multiple parts.

If you have a config file that pulls data from multiple Rest sources, you can use a simple Rest client like this that is based on HttpClient:

Library here: https://github.com/MelbourneDeveloper/RestClient.Net

```
  public class RestClient
    {
        #region Fields
        private readonly HttpClient _HttpClient = new HttpClient();
        #endregion

        #region Public Properties
        public Uri BaseUri => _HttpClient.BaseAddress;
        public Dictionary<string, string> Headers { get; private set; } = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        public AuthenticationHeaderValue Authorization { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<HttpStatusCode, Func<byte[], object>> HttpStatusCodeFuncs = new Dictionary<HttpStatusCode, Func<byte[], object>>();
        public IZip Zip;
        public ISerializationAdapter SerializationAdapter { get; }
        #endregion

        #region Constructor
        public RestClient(ISerializationAdapter serializationAdapter, Uri baseUri)
        {
            _HttpClient.BaseAddress = baseUri;
            _HttpClient.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 3, 0);
            SerializationAdapter = serializationAdapter;
        }
        #endregion

        #region Private Methods
        private async Task<T> Call<T>(string queryString, HttpVerb httpVerb, string contentType, object body = null)
        {
            _HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();

            if (Authorization != null)
            {
                _HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = Authorization;
            }

            HttpResponseMessage result = null;
            var isPost = httpVerb == HttpVerb.Post;
            if (!isPost)
            {
                _HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
                foreach (var key in Headers.Keys)
                {
                    _HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(key, Headers[key]);
                }
            }

            string bodyString = null;
            StringContent stringContent = null;
            byte[] data = null;

            switch (httpVerb)
            {
                case HttpVerb.Post:

                    if (body is string bodyAsString)
                    {
                        bodyString = bodyAsString;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (body != null)
                        {
                            data = await SerializationAdapter.SerializeAsync(body);
                            bodyString = SerializationAdapter.Encoding.GetString(data);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            bodyString = string.Empty;
                        }
                    }

                    stringContent = new StringContent(bodyString, Encoding.UTF8, contentType);

                    //Don't know why but this has to be set again, otherwise more text is added on to the Content-Type header...
                    stringContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(contentType);

                    stringContent.Headers.ContentLength = bodyString.Length;

                    foreach (var key in Headers.Keys)
                    {
                        stringContent.Headers.Add(key, Headers[key]);
                    }

                    result = await _HttpClient.PostAsync(queryString, stringContent);
                    break;

                case HttpVerb.Get:
                    result = await _HttpClient.GetAsync(queryString);
                    break;
                case HttpVerb.Delete:
                    result = await _HttpClient.DeleteAsync(queryString);
                    break;

                case HttpVerb.Put:
                case HttpVerb.Patch:

                    data = await SerializationAdapter.SerializeAsync(body);
                    bodyString = SerializationAdapter.Encoding.GetString(data);
                    var length = bodyString.Length;
                    stringContent = new StringContent(bodyString, SerializationAdapter.Encoding, contentType);

                    if (httpVerb == HttpVerb.Put)
                    {
                        result = await _HttpClient.PutAsync(queryString, stringContent);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var method = new HttpMethod("PATCH");
                        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(method, queryString)
                        {
                            Content = stringContent
                        };
                        result = await _HttpClient.SendAsync(request);
                    }
                    break;
            }

            if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var gzipHeader = result.Content.Headers.ContentEncoding.FirstOrDefault(h => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(h) && h.Equals("gzip", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
                if (gzipHeader != null && Zip != null)
                {
                    var bytes = await result.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
                    data = Zip.Unzip(bytes);
                }
                else
                {
                    data = await result.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
                }

                return await SerializationAdapter.DeserializeAsync<T>(data);
            }

            var errorData = await result.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();

            if (HttpStatusCodeFuncs.ContainsKey(result.StatusCode))
            {
                return (T)HttpStatusCodeFuncs[result.StatusCode].Invoke(errorData);
            }

            throw new HttpStatusException($"{result.StatusCode}.\r\nBase Uri: {_HttpClient.BaseAddress}. Full Uri: {_HttpClient.BaseAddress + queryString}", result.StatusCode, errorData);
        }
        #endregion

        #region Public Methods
        public async Task<T> GetAsync<T>()
        {
            return await GetAsync<T>(null);
        }

        public async Task<T> GetAsync<T>(string queryString, string contentType = "application/json")
        {
            return await Call<T>(queryString, HttpVerb.Get, contentType);
        }

        public async Task<TReturn> PostAsync<TReturn, TBody>(TBody body, string queryString, string contentType = "application/json")
        {
            return await Call<TReturn>(queryString, HttpVerb.Post, contentType, body);
        }

        public async Task<TReturn> PutAsync<TReturn, TBody>(TBody body, string queryString, string contentType = "application/json")
        {
            return await Call<TReturn>(queryString, HttpVerb.Put, contentType, body);
        }

        public async Task DeleteAsync(string queryString, string contentType = "application/json")
        {
            await Call<object>(queryString, HttpVerb.Delete, contentType, null);
        }

        public async Task<TReturn> PatchAsync<TReturn, TBody>(TBody body, string queryString, string contentType = "application/json")
        {
            return await Call<TReturn>(queryString, HttpVerb.Patch, contentType, body);
        }
        #endregion
}
```

Usage:

```
var countryCodeClient = new RestClientDotNet.RestClient(new NewtonsoftSerializationAdapter(), new Uri("http://services.groupkt.com/country/get/all"));
var countryData = await countryCodeClient.GetAsync<groupktResult<CountriesResult>>();
```